# How can I translate a script I wrote in SQL server to compute the odds ratios to Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

In SQL server, I wrote the following script to calculate the odds ratios based the probabilities of my test group divided by my control group. The script is as follows:

```
--Compute the odds ratios from the model  
select a.column1, a.uvs as testuvs. b.uvs as controluvs
       , [odds]=case when b.uvs>0 then a.puvs/b.puvs else Null end 
into unique_visitor_odds 
from control_probabilties b
    inner join test_probabilities a
    on a.column1=b.column2
 where a.uvs>24 and b.uvs>24 
 order by [odds] desc
```

I am not sure how to write this in Postgresql.

Comment: IS `a.uvs as testuvs. b.uvs as controluvs` a typo?

Comment: Hi. It is not a typo. This script runs fine in SQL server. uvs is designated as unique users.

Answer (score 1):

The code is remarkably similar:

```
create table unique_visitor_odds as
    select tp.column1, tp.uvs as testuvs, cp.uvs as controluvs,
           tp.puvs / nullif(cp.puvs, 0) as odds
    from control_probabilties cp inner join
         test_probabilities tp
         on tp.column1 = cp.column2
    where cp.uvs > 24 and tp.uvs > 24 
    order by odds desc ;
```

I removed the `case` statement in the `select`.  That is handled by the `where`.  Postgres is smart enough to respect the `where` when reporting errors.  And, you can prevent a divide by zero by using `nullif()`.

Except fro the `create table as` and `into` clauses, the same code works in both databases.

Also, the `order by` is suspicious.  I'm actually surprised the SQL Server allows it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the potential type between your second and third column in the `SELECT` clause and the oddball alias syntax, everything should translate to postgres easily:

```
SELECT a.column1,
    a.uvs AS testuvs,
    b.uvs AS controluvs,
    CASE WHEN b.uvs > 0 THEN a.puvs / b.puvs ELSE NULL END AS odds
INTO unique_visitor_odds
FROM control_probabilties b
INNER JOIN test_probabilities a ON a.column1 = b.column2
WHERE a.uvs > 24 AND b.uvs > 24
ORDER BY odds DESC
```