# I need help translating a script from SQL server to Postgresql to calculate odds ratios for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help adapting the code found in this previous question [How can I translate a script I wrote in SQL server to compute the odds ratios to Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480456/how-can-i-translate-a-script-i-wrote-in-sql-server-to-compute-the-odds-ratios-to)
 to include two columns in Postgresql. This is what I have as of now. I am getting syntax errors.

```
    --Compute the odds ratios from the model 
    SELECT a."column1", a."column2"
    a.uvs AS testuvs,
    b.uvs AS controluvs,
    CASE WHEN b.uvs > 0 THEN a.puvs / b.puvs ELSE NULL END AS odds
    INTO "bivariate_odds"
    FROM "control_group_probabilities" b
    INNER JOIN "test_group_probabilties" a ON 
    a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2
    WHERE a.uvs > 24 AND b.uvs > 24
    ORDER BY odds DESC
```

In SQL server, I would run the following script without any trouble:

```
    --compute the odds ratios 
    select a.column1, b.column2, a.totaluvs as totaltestuvs, a.uvs as 
    testuvs, b.totaluvs as totalcontroluvs, b.uvs as controluvs
    , odds= case when b.puvs>0.000001 then a.puvs/b.puvs else null end
    into bivariate_odds
    from test_group_probabilties a
    inner join control_group_probabilities b
    on a.column1=b.column1
    and a.column2=b.column2
```

The SQL server code is what I would like to express in Postgresql.

Comment: use `create table as` instead of `select into` and the code should be fine.

Comment: specifically `CREATE TABLE bivariate_odds AS SELECT ....` [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

Comment: I am getting this error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 3:     a.uvs AS testuvs,

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of line 1.